# ASP.NET Core Add parameter to controller's Create method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My controller's Create method binds to a TestCase object:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, Description")] TestCase testCase)
```

and the View that does the model bind takes a ViewModel in, which is specified like so:

```
 public class CreateTestCaseViewModel
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public TestCase TestCase { get; set; }
    }
```

My view's code (which is just a form where you input Name and Description, and submit) is:

```
@model CreateTestCaseViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create Test Case</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TestCase.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label">
</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="TestCase.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TestCase.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TestCase.Description" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @*<input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />*@
            <input asp-for="TestCase.Description" textarea class="form-control" id="Description" rows="5"/>

            <span asp-validation-for="TestCase.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div>
        <a asp-action="Details">Back to List</a>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

My goal is for my method to be able to take the ProjectName as an argument as well:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, Description")] TestCase testCase, string projectName)
```

How can I add it from the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller action to accept your view model and add the new parameter to the Bind list (or remove the Bind attribute entirely which will accept all fields):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, Description, ProjectName")] CreateTestCaseViewModel createTestCaseViewModel)
```

Then add an input for ProjectName to the view:

```
<input asp-for="ProjectName" type="text" />
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new input for the projectname, it's there already, I just wanted to store it without using Session. I also tried it and couldn't bind to the view model's properties...Must I rename them?

Comment: Use a hidden field like the other answer suggests, then. Both answers so far are good solutions.

Comment: If you're having trouble, remove the `[Bind("")]` from your Create action until you sort it out. You can also try using `@Html.EditorFor(Model.TestCase.Name)` rather than the `asp-for` tag helpers to make sure you're targeting the correct property name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use in controller the same model as in View.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateTestCaseViewModel model)
```

then in View you can create `@Model.EditorFor(Model.ProjectName)` if you need an input of ProjectName `@Model.HiddenFor(Model.ProjectName)` if you need just store value from Model.
**Update** You can put it right after element `<div class="form-horizontal">`
Actually it is not matter where, this element will be hidden from the user. The only requirement it should be inside your `<form asp-action="Create">` element

Comment: I don't need an input for this, it's a value I already have, so I should use @Model.HiddenFor(Model.ProjectName) , but where in the html structure should that be put? And also how will I bind the data from the form to that viewmodel?

Comment: @JDoe it will automatically resolve all bindings inside form. So if you will add hidden input its value will be passed to controller

Comment: After I bound the viewmodel in my view, the TestCase object inside my view is null actually (the projectname is ok). What can the problem be?